# Ignore parameter in getBy****() function in MongoRepository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongorepository

I'm using MongoRepository in my service. In my case, I have three field whose names are "Name", "Age" and "Gender". I could have following methods in my interface to query the data:

```
List<People> getByName(String name);
List<People> getByAge(String age);
List<People> getByNameAndGender(String name, String gender);
...and so on...
```

Now I want to query data with every combination of these 3 fields, so I need to write 7 (3 + 3 + 1) methods here and it is really ugly.

I tried to write something like

```
List<People> getByNameAndAgeAndGender(String name, String age, String gender);
```

And if the input has only two fields: name = Chris, age = 18, then I could call

```
List<People> peoples = getByNameAndAgeAndGender("Chris", "18", "*")
```

to get the list of people whose name is Chris and age is 18. How can I achieve this goal? I really don't want to write a big "if...else if...else if..." body. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<People> getByNameLikeAndAgeLikeAndGenderLike(String name, String age, String gender);
```

Comment: Thanks @TheKojuEffect ! It works for the case that if some parameters are missed. But all fields with "like" may cause other problem. For example: If I want to get all the people who calls Chris and 18 years old,  a 18 year-old people who called Christian may also be in the list because Christian is "like" Chris.

Comment: Hey @KeLiu, in that case, the solution that came into my mind is to create a custom implementation. I don't think it is possible with method name query. All the Best,